# "details": "not found" in django rest json response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm a newbie in Django Rest Framework. I am building an E-commerce API using postgresql as database for science fair project. I am getting "detail": "not found" as json response whenever I want to check the list of orders for a particular user. I have given the blocks of code below:

> In views.py

```
class OrderListAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderListSerializer
    lookup_fields = ['customer']
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'customer'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        a = Orders.objects.filter(customer=self.kwargs['customer'])
        return a
```

> In serializers.py

```
class OrderListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = "__all__"
```

> In urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import OrderListAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    path('orders/list/<customer>/', OrderListAPIView.as_view(), name='order-list')
]
```

> Response getting from the above code

```
{
    "detail": "not found"
}
```

> Expected Response

```
[
  {
    "ord_id": "ffa19b9b-650b-4c49-89bd-eb72f7b3c3b4",
    "product": "57cbd4a2-1c79-47a6-bf95-74ee3402e703",
    "ord_quantity": 10,
    "ord_price": 118.0,
    "ord_date": "2022-03-13T13:40:22.212586Z",
    "ord_status": "Pending",
    "customer": "08eba6ca-3f7c-4054-8184-d8ac341579e9"
  }
]
```

Is there anything which is wrong in these lines of code or anything which I forgot to implement or missed something?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What you are passing inside `['customer']`?

Comment: @FaisalNazik **customer** is a field name in Orders model which is a foreign key in that Orders model.

Comment: modify the URL to `path('orders/list/<str:customer>/', OrderListAPIView.as_view(), name='order-list'`

Comment: I tried that approach but getting the same result **"detail": "not found".**